# Iterate over a List of objects in Dart and present properties of object as a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    array arr = [MenuItem1, MenuItem2, MenuItem3]

    class MenuItem{
        String desc;
        String id;
    }
```

For the above class and array, how would I present them as a dynamic list flutter?

Rows of  `Row(chidren[Text((desc),Text((id)])`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Dart 2.3 you can use [Collection For](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists):

```
return Row(children:
[for (MenuItem item in arr ) Text(item.desc)]
);
```

Since you want to return 2 Widgets for each item in the array, you can combine this with the [Spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator):

```
return Row(children:
    [for (MenuItem item in arr ) ...[Text(item.desc),Text(item.id)]]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you to update the list dynamically.

```
 ListView.builder(
        itemCount: arr.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[Text(arr[index].desc), Text(arr[index].id)],
          );
        },
      )
```